# Unable To Post Webhook To C# Application On Azure

Tags: c#, azure, woocommerce

I am working on an email program for a WordPress WooCommerce store. I have added a webhook into the WooCommerce settings in order to hit a C# WebAPI application that I have created. I am trying to get run an email process every time an order is created.

I created an API controller with that accepts the JSON data that is sent over from WooCommerce, and when testing it locally from a Postman request, the controller is hit no problem.

I am trying to publish the application on Azure, and when I do, I am getting a 400 error from both the WooCommerce settings as well as any Postman requests.

I have tried setting

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"/>
</system.webServer>
```

in the web.config file, which then returned a 502 error from Postman, but still the same error on the WooCommerce webhook side.

I also tried re-deploying which did not work either.

I am able to view the homepage as well as the `API` controller link on the standard MVC homepage/menu view.

The controller is a standard API controller inheriting from the APIController class:

`public class OrdersController : ApiController`

and it contains one method, `ProcessOrders`, with an `[HttpGet, HttpPost]` attribute on it, and a route of `/api/orders/callback`.

The controller is responsible for inserting the payload from the webhook into the database and then it uses some other classes email out some specific information about the product.

Is there some kind of setting that needs to be set in the Azure portal or on the `web.config` file? I am not very experienced with Azure so I am not too familiar if there is anything else that needs to be done for this.

#### Azure Information

I am deploying to azure from quick publish inside Visual Studio

- A Pay-As-You-Go resource group
- .Net Framework `version 4.7`
- Remote debugging enabled
- `Web App` app service
- The only App service setting is `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` set to 6.9.1

I have tried both Release and Debug configurations, the connection is valid when trying the Validate Connection option inside configuration, the File Publish Options are all unchecked (Remove additional files at destination, precompile during publishing, exclude files from app_data folder) and the publish works fine, and the app is accessible, except for the api controller.

The project is built as a .Net framework `version 4.6.1` with Web API.

Thanks in advance for any help!

#### Edit

I have removed the parameter that was part of the original method that is being hit by the API, and I am now getting the error of `No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI`. I have tried changing the `Route` data annotation as well as just making it `HttpGet` to see if it was accessible, and it is not working. I created a second action on the controller just to test returning a string, and that worked without problem, so I am not sure why it is not accessible. The intro to the method is as follows:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/orders/callback")]
public string Callback() { return "Test"; }
```

I also updated this method to try just returning a simple string and it does not work. I also adjusted the second test method to accept a string POSTed to it and it is returning `The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'`.

This method looks like the following:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/orders/new")]
public string SecondCallback(string payload) {
  return payload;
}
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to fill in some more Azure-related information? What service are you deploying to, how are you trying to deploy, what kind of output you are seeing, etc. Those bits are probably the most relevant to your problem. Is your API ASP.NET or ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Did you try to hit directly to your api from postman?

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron Yes I tried hitting the API directly from Postman and I was able to access it fine as localhost before I published it to Azure and access all of the data accordingly.

Comment: @nlawalker Yes I just updated it with some more azure-specific information, thanks for the advice!